# Stack map pointers/icons in Mapquest Map

Tags: mapquest

I am using the mapquest API with the open source data.

My icons are scattered all around the world, but some are close together, i.e several in London.

Is there a way to show that there is more than one marker at a location? At present they are disappearing until you zoom in closer, but there is nothing to indicate that there is a reason to zoom!

Any ideas appreciated,
Thanks
Dave

UPDATE: I'm unable to answer my own question due to not having any reputation, so here is the answer which I finally found in the manual:

The technique I was looking for is called POI Decluttering:
http://developer.mapquest.com/web/documentation/sdk/javascript/v7.0/poi#declutter

It's not particularly pretty, but it does solve the problem.

Copied here for reference:

```
/*Construct the POIs and set automatic decluttering for each.*/
var declutter1=new MQA.Poi( {lat:39.743943, lng:-105.020089} );
declutter1.setDeclutterMode(true);

var declutter2=new MQA.Poi( {lat:39.743943, lng:-105.020089} );
declutter2.setDeclutterMode(true);

var declutter3=new MQA.Poi( {lat:39.753012, lng:-105.018542} );
declutter3.setDeclutterMode(true);

/*This will add the POIs to the map in the map's default shape collection.*/
map.addShape(declutter1);
map.addShape(declutter2);
map.addShape(declutter3);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also change the bias of each successive Poi to have more control of how they are displayed., this requires you to keep track of all the duplicates and how many are at the same location.

```
declutter1.setBias({x:0, y:12});
```

For my application I change just the y Bias by 12 each time I have a duplicate.  The second Poi at a location sets y=12, the third y=24, etc.  This stacks the POI's up below one another but you can customize how best fits your application.

It is up to you to determine what is a duplicate point.  If you just use lat/lon then your third point above would not be included in the stack because it doesn't have the exact same values.